# Java SE binary crash

Tags: swing, crash, java

I have a Java swing application that subscribes to a lot of data and displays this data in various ways. Under heavy load I have come to encounter that the JRE simply stops working with message "Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working". This obviously shuts down my application and I need to restart it. I have tried to google for ways to troubleshoot this issue as I do not get a stacktrace in my code or anything that I can work with but I have found very little useful information beyond upgrading/re-installing the JRE and running virus scans. I have done both of these measures and rebooted the server but the problem still persists. I have tried to monitor the process with Java VisualVM (see dump below) but I am no expert on this tool and may not know what to look for. The observation that I have made is that the 'crashes' appear to coincide with Garbage Collections.

The issue is quite easy to reproduce and occurs after about 10 minutes of running the application. I do not run the application with any specific jvm parameters. The Java version is 1.6.0_31 (was _25 before upgrade) and I run on Windows 7 64-bit.

In the pic below from VisualVM the Java binary has just stopped working which appears to coincide with the GC-run.
[image: Dump from Java VisualVM]

Any help or ideas so that I can troubleshoot or remedy the problem is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you use any JNI extensions?

Comment: It seems GC is not happening properly.

Comment: Maybe it worth try JRockit and compare the behaviour.

Comment: @DmitryOvsyanko Thanks. I will try to search for any potential deadlocks in my code as suggested by Ernest below but if I come up short with that I may try JRockit.

Answer (score 3):

Three things to check:

1. If you've implemented the `finalize()` method anywhere, make sure it doesn't directly or indirectly lock any objects; this can cause a catatrophic deadlock correlated with GC.
2. If you've got native code, any number of weird things can happen if the code is not using global references correctly, including deadlocks and weird memory corruption, which would again correlate with GC activity.
3. Finally, GC might just be "stirring the pot" and exposing vanilla deadlocks which exist otherwise in the application; check your synchronization protocols.

Comment: is that message - binary has stopped working - always a deadlock?

Comment: It's either a deadlock, or a bug in the JVM, Windows, or a native library. He tried two different Java patchlevels so a JVM bug isn't too likely, and he's not using native code per a comment; so it's most lilely either a Windows bug (i.e., a bug in some Windows DLL used by the JVM) or it's a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks. I will check into 1+3 as they may be potential candidates. I only wish I could have gotten a little more information about where it breaks as it will be cumbersome and difficult to run the application in debug-mode with the load in question.

Answer (score 2):

Garbage collection pauses the VM's application threads while it happens, which might be exposing a race condition somewhere.

Comment: OK. Any thoughts on how I can troubleshoot that?

Comment: See also [*ThreadCheckingRepaintManager*](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2006/02/debugging_swing.html) concerning EDT violations.